# Missing id field in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using `DjangoCrispyForms` and I have created a `ModelForm` for my `User` model.
In `Meta` class I have registered what fields I would like to have in the form, one of them is `id` of User.
The problem is that this `id` field doesn't appear in the form, I had to manually add such a field to my form class. It gets more complex when I want to save changes to DB and I need to extract `id` from `cleaned_data`.

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.IntegerField() # needed to add this

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

        self.fields['id'].widget = HiddenInput()

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Edit user',
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'is_superuser',
                'id'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Save')
            ))

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if len(User.objects.filter(username=username)) > 1:
            self.add_error('username', 'Username is taken.')
        if len(User.objects.filter(email=email)) > 1:
            self.add_error('email', 'Account with this email exists')
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(EditUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        data_id = self.cleaned_data.get('id') # need to get this from data
        instance.id = data_id # and set id for instance
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_superuser'] # here we can see that id is actually present in fields
```

Am I missing something or is it how it supposed to be?

Comment: Normally the `id` is not in the form. The URL is used to specify the id, and it is usually not `editable`.

Comment: So is my approach good? Or should I call `.save(commit=False)` from the view, then add id to the instance and then save instance?

Comment: Where is the view located? Usually the idea is that the form is used for both *creation* and *editing* of objects. The views however are a bit different in the sense that for an edit, the URL determines the `id`, and the corresponding object is passed to the form. Typically a form is not used to edit/show the id, since that is usually not something that matters to a user. A user wants to make for example an order, the fact that it is row 4105 in the database, is not really relevant.

Comment: See for example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: That's true that this is not relevant to user, but is to me to know which id i need to edit. Though I understand that i can get id from url in the view. But what approach is better? Also I don't want to have an option to change password in edit form, that's why I have two separate forms for creation and editing.

Comment: If the id is auto_increment why would you need to handle it in your form? You shouldn't touch the field at all. You also don't need two separate forms if you want a specific field not showing, you just have to change the template, adding `{% if object %}`. If you need to address something in the form for created object you could use `if self.instance.pk`. It seems to me that you are duplicating logic unnecessarily. Even more, every time you need to change some aspect of the form, you have to do it _twice_, which is not a good practice.